How to create confluence page from comments in code?
I have code uploaded to GIT and I want to use the comments to create a confluence page.
For example, I have a script with utility functions that do various things.
Let's say I use comments like:
// === START
// FUNCTION NAME: function1
// FUNCTION DESCRIPTION: This function aims to do x and y 
// FUNCTION PARAMETER: [table] - a dataframe
// FUNCTION OUTPUT: [boolean] - type of output expected 
// FUNCTION AUTHOR: John Doe
// === END

Is there a way to use the above comments and create a confluence with that information ?

There is a Confluence REST API to create a page, so it should be possible to have a program to extract your comments and upload them. Do you have a more specific question?

qdoc can create docs in a format which is easier to upload to Confluence https://code.kx.com/developer/libraries-scripts/#qdoc-documentation-generation

Confluence supports a limited form of markdown which may be of use, combined with the REST API to programmatically generate this from code comments.
The links below should get you started:
https://support.atlassian.com/confluence-cloud/docs/insert-confluence-wiki-markup/
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Insert-Confluence-Wiki-Markdown-via-API/qaq-p/667936
